# Run a php script everytime admin login happens from within a module

Tags: magento-2.1

I have written a custom module.

I need to execute a local php script everytime an admin login occours, using code within the custom module.

How can I do that?

Comment: you will require use of observer and call  function  on admin login event .

Comment: @akgola Pls write an answer to illustrate how that can be done. it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a module and use observer.

create `events.xml` file at path `vendor/modulename/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

add the below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="backend_activity" instance="vendor\modulename\Observer\adminuserlogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer file `adminuserlogin.php` at path `vendor\modulename\Observer` and insert the below code,

```
<?php

class adminuserlogin implements ObserverInterface
{

   public function __construct(
    ) {

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //implement here what you want
    }
}
```

This will help you.

Comment: creating `events.xml` file inside `vendor/modulename/etc/adminhtml/events.xml` is changing the core magento.. It's not permited..

Comment: I mean app/code/companyname/modulename/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

Comment: I also need to create a `registration.php` and then run `setup:upgrade`. right?

Comment: Yes,you will require follow all steps same as other modules in magento2.